# Parse LiveQuery Separate Server with Redis

Tags: heroku, redis, parse-server

#### Issue Description

When running separate Parse Server and Parse LiveQuery Servers with Redis for scalability, the Parse Server does not publish to Redis in order to push down new updates to the LiveQuery Servers.

Current Setup is as follows:

--MAIN PARSE SERVER--

```

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: process.env.DATABASE_URI,
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN,
  appId: process.env.APP_ID,
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY, 
  fileKey: process.env.FILE_KEY, 
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL,  
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Random","ClassNames"], 
      redisUrl: process.env.REDIS_URL
  }
```

```

--PARSE LIVEQUERY SERVER--

```

```
var api = new ParseServer({
    appId: process.env.APP_ID,
    masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY,
    serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL
});

var app = express();

var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/leap';
app.use(mountPath, api);

var port = process.env.PORT;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);

httpServer.listen(port, function() {
        console.log('parse-live-query-server running on port ' + port + '.');
});

// This will enable the Live Query real-time server
ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer, {
  redisURL: process.env.HEROKU_REDIS_URL
});
```

```

#### Steps to reproduce

- Create a main parse server app on Heroku, add a Heroku Redis as an Add-on
- Create a separate parse LiveQuery server app on Heroku and link to the Redis
- Set all environment variables in Heroku accordingly (with REDIS_URL linking to the updating Redis add-on url given when connecting to the Redis Instance)
- Upgrade to paid dynos and Redis
- Point client app subscriptions at LiveQuery Server URL
- Send a new message from subscribed clients

#### Expected Results

Expect the Main Parse Server to publish the updates to the LiveQuery to Redis to be read by the LiveQuery Server (subscriptions) which in turn would call the handle method in the client.

#### Actual Outcome

The message was created but the handle method in the client was never called.

Keep in mind that this setup will work when the main parse server and LiveQuery server are run locally with Redis being run from Heroku.

#### Environment Setup

- **Server**

  - parse-server version : 2.5.3
  - Operating System: Heroku Dyno and locally MacOS High Sierra
  - Hardware: Heroku Web App
  - See above description regarding local and Heroku configurations
- **Database**
  MLab

#### Logs/Trace

Redis shows two active-connections, Main Parse Server shows the creation of the message object, reloading the client view will show the created messages.

Answer (score 0):

You have the parameter "redisURL" mistyped on the publishing side. It's "redisURL", not "redisUrl".